# FFmpeg Block Motion Compensation Only

Tags: video-processing, video-compression

is there a way to **just perform block motion compensation** using ffmpeg command line (i.e. no addition of residual encodings). I want to compare the quality of the video frames produced using various block-motion algorithms.

I want to be able to extract motion vectors and generate motion compensated frames as in the SckitVideo Library (http://www.scikit-video.org/stable/motion.htmlhttp://www.scikit-video.org/stable/motion.html). This code is however limited to I,P,P frame sequences. 
There must be a way of achieving the same result for I, B, B, P, B, B, I sequences.

The *extract_mvs.c* example in FFmpeg's github repository uses FFmpeg's libav library to extract motion vectors from side information in the video encoding.(https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/tree/master/doc/examples)

At the moment I am looking for a way to do the compensation (ffmpeg command line would be preferable but reference to coding examples using ffmpeg's libav library would also be much appreciated).

Thanks in advance!